# How to use slider option for div tags using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, slider

I have listed two div tags Nut 1 and Nut 2, I am trying to add a slider in such way that div tags moves horizontally. I tried many tutorials but I couldnt do it. and I am not sure can slider also be responsive like segements of the page. With only Images I was able to make a slider but with along with other content I couldnt.

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
      <!-- Nut 1-->
      <figure class="images_in_nuts">
        <img src="images/almonds.jpg" />
      </figure>
      <div class="nut_text">
        <h2>Almond</h2>
        <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
        <p>
          Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
          Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
          Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
          phenolic acids
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- Nut 1 Ends-->
      <!-- Nut 1-->
      <figure class="images_in_nuts">
        <img src="images/almonds.jpg" />
      </figure>
      <div class="nut_text">
        <h2>Almond</h2>
        <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
        <p>
          Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
          Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
          Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
          phenolic acids
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- Nut 1 Ends-->
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #ebebeb;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 5px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 20px;
  animation: slider 20s infinite;
  float: inline-end;
}


.images_in_nuts {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nut_text {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.rich_in {
  text-align: center;
}
```

I have added a link to pen code https://codepen.io/gladwin-james/pen/qBqRxKw

Comment: This will be mostly JavaScript's work. Without this, you will have a static "slider" with one image that will never change. I recommend you to use bootstrap carousel or swiper-js since it can be used as a "standalone". :-) These days it's pointless to use self-made components such as sliders, it is waste of time. :-)

Comment: @jozpac thankyou for the suggestion realted to bootstrap. I did a carousel and I am facing a small error, if you have time can you please take a look at this? please

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the following link...

- Using bootstrap for [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp).
- Using HTML & CSS only for [click here](https://css-tricks.com/can-get-pretty-far-making-slider-just-html-css/)

I hope it is helpful for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's a slideshow you are trying to achieve.
However I made an example that illustrates what I think you are trying to implement:

[Example](https://codepen.io/saief-al-faour/pen/YzpVExX)

Here is the code I used from www3schools.com
You should be good to go if you re-use my sample
CSS:

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text">
     <h2>Almond</h2>
        <h3>Rich In</h3>
    Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
          Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
          Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
          phenolic acids</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text"> <h2>Almond</h2>
        <h3>Rich In</h3>
    Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
          Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
          Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
          phenolic acids</div></div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/14/20/11/flowers-324175_960_720.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="text"> <h2>Almond</h2>
        <h3>Rich In</h3>
    Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
          Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
          Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
          phenolic acids</div></div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>
```

Javascript (remember the script tag):

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: MishMish hey man, link is not working. Can you please check it once, please?